# does bibliographystyle ' elsarticle-num ' need any specific package to apply?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm using elsarticle-num as bibliographystyle  in my article but my references can't be shown, what problem might be exist?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please tell us (a) which document class you employ and (b) more about what "my references can't be shown" entails. E.g., do you experience issues with the formatted bibliography, the citation call-outs, or both? Does BibTeX throw error and/or warning messages? If so, what do the messages say?

Comment: A separate comment: Usually, the `elarticle-num` and `elsarticle-harv` bibliography styles are employed alongside the `elsarticle` document class. If you employ this document class, it loads the `natbib` citation management package; it shouldn't be necessary to load this package explicitly. If, on the other hand, you do *not* employ the `elsarticle` class, you will probably need to load `natbib` on your own. That's why I asked which document class is in use.